# Showing AlertDialog when button is clicked problem

Tags: android

I've got button in my Activity and I want to show AlertDialog when button is clicked:

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
     case R.id.btnDetailedCall:
        final String[] phoneArray=ad.getPhone().split(" ");

        if(phoneArray.length>1){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Title");
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(phoneArray, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    selectedPhone=phoneArray[which];
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
            dialog.show();
  }
```

When I pass "this" to AlertDialog constructor code runs normally but dialog does not appear on the screen. I believe that "this" is not the right reference here, so I tried getBaseContext() and got `WindowManager$BadTockenException: Unable to add window -- tocken null is not for an application`

Will appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: `this` works for me. Have you checked if something else is not working as expected?

Comment: If you remove builder.setSingleChoiceItems(...) does it show then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing "this" may reference the wrong object, trying passing "ClassName.this" where ClassName is the name of the actual class that you're using - here is a sample block of code that I use when requesting for user text input in an application that may be of help:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyClassName.this);
alert.setTitle("My title");
alert.setMessage("Some info I want to tell the user about");
final EditText input = new EditText(MyClassName.this);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
alert.setView(input);
alert.setPositiveButton("Do it", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        try{
            int value = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
            doIt(value);
        }catch (Exception e){
            finish();
        }
    }
});
alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
        finish();
    }
});
alert.show();
```

Comment: Just realised that a key difference between your code and mine that you are using "builder.create()", and I'm effectively using "builder.show()" - see if using builder.show() makes any difference.

Comment: Tried this, but dialog still does not appear on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(className.this);
```

where className is the name of your Activity class i.e. the main outer class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( getApplicationContext() );
```

Comment: This throws exception mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try builder.show() instead of your last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding the "new" keyword in front of your AlertDialog.Builder statement and link the others to the initial statement by just doing ".setTitle..." etc. on the subsequent lines.  I have some that work like that.

Ex.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Test")
    .create()
    .show();
```